# Civicrm consultancy

Tags: civicrm-home

Good afternoon,

I am Specialist content for an association.
We have recently started working with Civi and I would like to contact someone expert in the platform for certain issues. I don't know if this is the right place.
Mainly what I need is a support or consultant for civi with whom I can solve and advance in certain aspects.

I look forward to hearing from you,
Best regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://chat.civicrm.org would be a good place to start. Just ask your question there.

You can also use https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors